# Insert text after image inside Elementor posts loop via hook

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I'm trying to insert text after image inside an Elementor posts loop (basically regular posts loop).

I can't find the right hook for that, I found so far after long research only `the_title` hook, that in charge on the the title of each post. But I need it after the image and not inside the title.

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpb_new_title', 10, 2 );
function wpb_new_title( $title, $id ) {
    global $post;
    if(!is_page( 'Wishlist' )){
       if('post' == get_post_type($id)){
            $exclusive = get_field('exclusive', $id);   // pass the id into get_field
            $title = $title .' Custom Text Here '. $exclusive;
        }
    }
    return $title;
}
```

Here is my current code, that works, though not after the image.

What is the correct way to insert custom text after post image?

Comment: Try to use the filter hook `post_thumbnail_html`… see it in [the source code](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.2/src/wp-includes/post-thumbnail-template.php#L235) as it has 5 available arguments